# Classification problem with bayesian networks (TensorFlow Probability)

Tags: python, tensorflow, bayesian-networks

I'm having some trouble working with tensorflow probability in the last few days.

I have trained the frequentist version of this network and reached individual accuracies above 0.99. Although, when trying the bayesian version, the accuracies are equivalent to a dummy model. This is weird as I suspect the results might not differ much.

As I'm new to bayesian approaches I would like to know if I'm missing something here... I didn't found much information and examples that suits me.

In this model I'm making predictions around the presence (1) of absence (0) of 3 properties (Y), which may occur simultaneously or not.

I would really appreciate some insights.

Thank you all in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from main import get_data

#%% Configuration
config = {"ID_prefix" : "Bayesian_CNN_Flipout",
          "mode" : "classification",
          "optimizer" : "Adam",
          "loss" : "binary_crossentropy",
          "monitor" : "val_loss",
          "patience" : 10,
          "lr" : 0.001,
          "repetitions" : 3,
          "X_reshape" : True}

#%% Get data
data = get_data("dataset.csv", config)
```

my data have the followings dimensions:

```
data["X_train"].shape
Out[8]: (39375, 1024, 1)

data["Y_train"].shape
Out[9]: (39375, 3)

data["X_val"].shape
Out[10]: (13125, 1024, 1)

data["Y_val"].shape
Out[11]: (13125, 3)

data["X_test"].shape
Out[13]: (17500, 1024, 1)

data["Y_test"].shape
Out[14]: (17500, 3)
```

The structure of the network is:

```
#%% Model structure
config["inputs"] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(data["X_train"].shape[1], data["X_train"].shape[2]))

layer = config["inputs"]
layer = tfp.layers.Convolution1DFlipout(filters=10, kernel_size=5, strides=1, activation="relu")(layer)
layer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(layer)
layer = tfp.layers.Convolution1DFlipout(filters=10, kernel_size=5, strides=1, activation="relu")(layer)
layer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(layer)
layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(layer)

config["outputs"] = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(units=3, activation="sigmoid")(layer)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=config["inputs"], outputs=config["outputs"])

model.compile(optimizer=config["optimizer"], loss=config["loss"])

tf.keras.backend.set_value(model.optimizer.learning_rate, config["lr"])

earlystopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor=config["monitor"],
                                                 patience=config["patience"],
                                                 restore_best_weights=True)

#%% Fit model
history = model.fit(data["X_train"], data["Y_train"],
                    validation_data=[data["X_val"], data["Y_val"]],
                    epochs=999999,
                    callbacks=[earlystopping])

#%% Classification metrics
pred_train = np.zeros([config["repetitions"], data["Y_train"].shape[0], data["Y_train"].shape[1]])
pred_val = np.zeros([config["repetitions"], data["Y_val"].shape[0], data["Y_val"].shape[1]])
pred_test = np.zeros([config["repetitions"], data["Y_test"].shape[0], data["Y_test"].shape[1]])
accuracy_train = np.zeros([config["repetitions"], 1, data["Y_train"].shape[1]])
accuracy_val = np.zeros([config["repetitions"], 1, data["Y_val"].shape[1]])
accuracy_test = np.zeros([config["repetitions"], 1, data["Y_test"].shape[1]])
for i in range(config["repetitions"]):
    pred_train[i] = model.predict(data["X_train"]).round()
    pred_val[i] = model.predict(data["X_val"]).round()
    pred_test[i] = model.predict(data["X_test"]).round()
    accuracy_train[i] = (data["Y_train"]==pred_train[i]).mean(0)
    accuracy_val[i] = (data["Y_val"]==pred_val[i]).mean(0)
    accuracy_test[i] = (data["Y_test"]==pred_test[i]).mean(0)
```

Comment: That's probably because you omit KL-Weighting step. You need to define divergence_fn for both weights and biases and divide to the total number of samples.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @Frightera. Unfortunately, correcting "kernel_divergence_fn" and "bias_divergence_fn" in the Flipout layers didn't improve the model. The initial loss was indeed considerably smaller but it eventually converged to the same loss I had without the correction.

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest additions?

Comment: Sure. I just updated the code in the question.

Comment: Is the data normalized? Also can you try to pass same divergence_fn to all layers, not separate like kernel & bias divergence_fn. And `bias_posterior_fn` takes `is_singular = True` by default, set it to `is_singular = False`. If those do not solve the problem, you need to add loss values to the question for further investigation.

Comment: The data is normalized. I updated the code in the question as instructed but got the same results. I also added the loss at the end. The minimum loss reached is still the same (Loss = 0.6830).

Comment: Why do you have a binary loss with three target classes?

Comment: @NathanFurnal In this model I'm making predictions around the presence or absence of 3 properties, which may occur simultaneously or not. Example, first target tells me about the presence or absence of a cat, second target tells me about the presence or absence of a dog and third  target tells me about the presence or absence of a bird. The target can predict the presence of a bird and a dog and the absence of a cat, for example.

Comment: Alright then it should be good on the loss' end. Have you tried setting up your own verification function and compare it with Keras' values.

Comment: Model configuration seems correct, did you also try adding more or removing some layers?

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I could manage to properly train my network with the final version of the code I updated in the question. Apparently, I missed some points while coding, as pointed out by @Frightera.

Comment: @Frightera, Can you please explain the impact of setting `is_singular = False` in `bias_posterior_fn`?

Comment: `is_singular=True` means that the values become point estimate rather than having a probability distribution. If you want your biases to become a prob. distribution it should be False.

Comment: Please roll back your edit and post the answer as an answer instead. Your question should remain strictly a question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**THE QUESTION WAS ANSWERED AND THE CODE BELOW WORKED PROPERLY:**

```
#%% Initial Imports
import shutil
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from main import get_data, update_results, main

#%% Configuration
config = {"Folder_ID" : "Bayesian_CNN_Flipout",
          "mode" : "classification",
          "optimizer" : "Adam",
          "loss" : "binary_crossentropy",
          "metrics" : "binary_accuracy",
          "monitor" : "val_binary_accuracy",
          "patience" : 10,
          "repetitions" : 5,
          "X_reshape" : True}

#%% Get data
data = get_data("dataset.csv", config)
```

my data have the followings dimensions:

```
data["X_train"].shape
Out[8]: (39375, 1024, 1)

data["Y_train"].shape
Out[9]: (39375, 3)

data["X_val"].shape
Out[10]: (13125, 1024, 1)

data["Y_val"].shape
Out[11]: (13125, 3)

data["X_test"].shape
Out[13]: (17500, 1024, 1)

data["Y_test"].shape
Out[14]: (17500, 3)
```

The structure of the network is:

```
#%% Model structure
divergence_fn = lambda q, p, ignore: tfp.distributions.kl_divergence(q, p)/data['X_train'].shape[0]

config["inputs"] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(data["X_train"].shape[1], data["X_train"].shape[2]))

layer  = config["inputs"]

layer = tfp.layers.Convolution1DFlipout(filters=2, kernel_size=5, strides=1, activation="relu", kernel_divergence_fn=divergence_fn, bias_divergence_fn=divergence_fn)(layer)
layer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(layer)
layer = tfp.layers.Convolution1DFlipout(filters=2, kernel_size=5, strides=1, activation="relu", kernel_divergence_fn=divergence_fn, bias_divergence_fn=divergence_fn)(layer)
layer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(layer)

layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(layer)
config["outputs"] = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(3, activation='sigmoid', kernel_divergence_fn=divergence_fn, bias_divergence_fn=divergence_fn)(layer)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=config["inputs"], outputs=config["outputs"])

model.compile(optimizer=config["optimizer"], loss=config["loss"])

earlystopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor=config["monitor"],
                                                 patience=config["patience"],
                                                 restore_best_weights=True)

#%% Fit model
history = model.fit(data["X_train"], data["Y_train"],
                    validation_data=[data["X_val"], data["Y_val"]],
                    epochs=999999,
                    callbacks=[earlystopping])
```